# Mac OS Chrome Browser: Archive Utility (Error 1) - Operation not permitted: Unable to expand downloaded zip

Tags: java, macos, google-chrome, zip, zipoutputstream

Background: We have written a java code to download zip from web location to local download folder. And downloaded zip is expanding fine with Window(including all browser) but we are facing issue in Mac OS with Chrome browser only.

Error: Archive Utility (Error 1) - Operation not permitted: Unable to expand downloaded zip

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I spent a couple of hours debugging.
It turned out that some function in my code sent some data to the output stream (printed some string).
As a result, the data was considered part of the zip file which caused it to corrupt.

I hope it helps.